# MySql Retrieving Data from multiple Tables then Insert limited values In another table

Tags: mysql

I have many tables with the same structure for each of my costumers.
All information are distinct for each table. 
For some reason, I need to create some temporary table with the same structure with 200 values everytime I run.
So let's assume I have 3 tables.
Costumer1, Costumer2, Costumer3.
All those tables have id, user_name, contact_name, contact_email, sent1, sent2, sent3, sent4, status.

I need some query to put inside costumer_tmp, only 200 values in total, from all those 3 tables, everytime I run the script. And everytime I run cant repeat the last values I got before.

So for example:

```
Costumer1

id = 29
user_name = test1
contact_name = contact1
contact_email = contact1@mail.com
sent1 = yes
sent2 = no
sent3 = no
sent4 = no
status = In Progress

Costumer2

id = 37
user_name = test2
contact_name = contact123
contact_email = contact123@mail.com
sent1 = yes
sent2 = no
sent3 = no
sent4 = no
status = In Progress

Costumer3

id = 87
user_name = test3
contact_name = contact231
contact_email = contact231@mail.com
sent1 = yes
sent2 = no
sent3 = no
sent4 = no
status = In Progress
```

How to Insert on costumer_tmp only 2 records of those 3 and next time I run the script don't repeat those 2 records, just insert only 1 record remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is a bit weird, but if I understand weel, how about something like : (not tested)

```
insert into costumer_tmp
select * from Costumer1 one where one.id not in (select id from costumer_tmp)
union all
select * from Costumer2 two where two.id not in (select id from costumer_tmp)
union all
select * from Costumer3 three where three.id not in (select id from costumer_tmp) LIMIT 200
```

Comment: Thanks @antoine.lange I know it's very weird but I need that to do some workaround :) It's getting me error with the union all. Something is wrong.

Comment: I've changed (three and) for (three where), it worked but I got Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'PRIMARY' with one record

Comment: Do you have the same ids in Costumer1, Costumer2 and Costumer3 ?

Comment: No, the column Id is auto incremental for each. But doesnt matter, I've put another condition and it worked for now. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @antoine.lange I got stuck again. I think I'll need some column like `costumer_tmp`.`tmp_id` to avoid conflicts or repeated `costumer(*)`.`id`. Some clue??